# OAuth Apps on a Single Domain

Tags: oauth

My company has a website. Let's pretend that it's hosted at `http://www.example.com`. I have three apps that I need to build for different teams. Users will have different permissions, possibly different OAuth logins, per app. I'd like to host apps on domains like:

- `http://www.example.com/apps/my-first-app`
- `http://www.example.com/apps/my-second-app`
- `http://www.example.com/apps/my-third-app`

My question is can I do this? I'm trying to understand if OAuth tokens are per *domain* or per *app/url*. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OAuth Tokens are indeed per domain / app / url.

I did read a while back you can create multiple tokens and store those in the db for the time being so that multiple users with multiple roles can use those tokens to do the things they are permitted to in one domain for instance. I cannot really remember where I read it, but once I do i'll get back to you as soon as possible

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to have multiple consumer apps like that. I'm not sure providers would work however.

Each consumer has a unique client ID and secret (and usually a callback url on the provider, github say). As long as each consumer application has a unique client ID I can't see why this wouldn't work - just create 3 applications on the provider and then make you set the callback urls correctly.